# Display list of missing firmwares

Tags: drivers, kernel, proprietary, firmware

How do I detect the missing firmwares. I can only see it when a new kernel is installed but seems rather silly to installed a kernel just to display this information.

Also, what is the official/most updated/conventional way to get these missing firmwares

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/hainan_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/oland_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/verde_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/pitcairn_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/tahiti_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/hawaii_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/radeon/bonaire_k_smc.bin for module radeon
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin for module i915
```

Comment: Does `dpkg --audit linux-firmware` shed any light?

Comment: returns nothing